# What is template void func<X>();?

Tags: c++, templates

I've seen the following code in cppreference page about enable_if:

```
struct X {
    enum { value1 = true, value2 = true };
};

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<T::value1, int> = 0>
void func() {} // #1

template void func<X>(); // What's this?
```

Could you please tell me what does template before function

```
template void func<X>();
```

mean?

cppreference link:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

Comment: [Explicit instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation).

Comment: "I've seen the following code in cppreference" - obviously, you should link to where you have seen this.

Comment: Added a link. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! What if I wrote just void func<X>();? Wouldn't such a declaration instantiate the template of function func?

Comment: You could, but not at namespace scope. It would look like you are trying to just execute it which you can't do there. You could put it in function though, but in this case it doesn't look like they actually intend to execute it.

Comment: I think, that is not the actual code my friend but an explanation for a  temporary result.